# Count the total number of occurrences of a word in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to know the number of times a word appears in my table (DataTables)

```
var numberOccurence = $('tr > td:nth-child(2):contains("'+ word +'")').length;
```

The problem is that it looks only on the visible part of the table,
that is, if there are 10 pages on DataTables, it only gives me the number of occurrences on the first page

How to do it?

**EDIT**
Here is the Html

```
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="fileTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Localisation</th>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Like</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= $order['date'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $order['localisation'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $order['user'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $order['like'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your HTML so we can see how complex (or simple) the table is

Comment: The other question would be are the other 'hidden' parts of the table actually rendered into HTML but just hidden through styling?

Comment: Hidden elements ought to be found with this method though. [Proof](https://jsfiddle.net/6f4go3y7/).

Comment: I added the html
The whole table is loaded but surely hidden by the style

Comment: @Proof it's a totally basic painting that can look like this : https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin, you could search the data of DataTable using `data()`

```
// Column name to search
var colName = 'columnName';
// Column index to search
var colIndex = 2;

var term = 'word';

// Get reference of DataTables API
var tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable();

// Get data (array of rows)
var data = tbl.data();

// Use filter function to search for term
var occurence = data.toArray().filter(function(row) {
   // If data is array of objects
   return row[colName].indexOf(term) !== -1;
   // If data is array of strings
   return row[colIndex].indexOf(term) !== -1;
}).length;
```

You can check the documentation about [data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data())

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand very well what corresponds 'colName' and 'colIndex' (I added the html of my table on my first post)

Comment: As I can see from your question you are searching the second column (nth-child(2)). So, you can set colIndex = 2

Comment: Use one of two, either search by column index (colIndex) or by column name (colName), depending on the type of data you get when you call tbl.data(). In your case, just set colName = 1 (zero based) and use "return row[colIndex].indexOf(term) !== -1;"

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but use the [**`$`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method along with the `:contains` selector instead :

```js
var count = table.$('td:contains("'+ term +'")').length;
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mLqreyfg/**

> $() : Perform a jQuery selection action on the full table